# serializing a tree map

Tags: java, jms, treemap

could some one please provide a working code to demonstrate how to serialize a tree map to byte[] in java? The key of the tree map is the time in seconds and milliseconds while the value is jms message received at that particular time.

Comment: Objectoutputstream? XML? Properties file? CSV?

Comment: serialize it to byte[] - as an Objectoutputstream? XML? Properties file? CSV? (a `byte[]` is not a format!)

Comment: Yes serialize it to bytes as an ObjectOutputStream

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the key and value types implement `Serializable`, you can simply use `ObjectObjectOutputStream` to do the serialization, and `ByteArrayOutputStream` to capture the output and turn it into a `byte[]`.

You should be able to figure out how to do it by reading the javadocs for `ObjectObjectOutputStream`  and `ByteArrayOutputStream`.  If you need information in a simpler form, there is lots of it in Oracle's Java tutorials, and in particular in the [basic I/O tutorial stream](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/index.html).

(The page on Byte Streams has a very important lesson in the section entitled "Always Close Streams".  Make sure that you read and understand what it is saying.)

Comment: The other thing to watch out for is that if the tree map uses a custom comparator, that comparator must also be serializable.